# How to setting SNMP in Debian 7?

Tags: debian, snmp

I have a problem when installing snmpd in debian 7. Smpd can not be accessed from outside (I use PRTG), I've set rocommunity to public, but not working. I am looking for a solution on google, but I get a different SNMP versions :(

here my snmpd.conf : http://xevil.or.id/snmpd.txt

sorry my english was poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You config clearly states:

```
agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
```

Your SNMP agent is listening on localhost. Make sure it's listening on a routable address your PRTG can reach.

Comment: just it x_x thank you so much bro.. my snmp works now :D thanks thanks...